# Lasagne: neural Network Image(character) classification. Selection of size output_num_units

Tags: python, theano, lasagne

I am performing classification with the help of neural network used in danielnouri's blog post.  The total size of the training data is 6300 samples. The data is 20*20 sized character pictures.  I am unable to figure out how to select the size of output_num_units. Total number of unique classes are 63. Shape of xtrain is (6283L, 400L) . Shape of yTrain is (6283L,).   Below is the code for the nueral network.

```
net1 = NeuralNet(
           layers=[  # three layers: one hidden layer
                   ('input', layers.InputLayer),
                   ('hidden', layers.DenseLayer),
                   ('output', layers.DenseLayer),
               ],
           # layer parameters:
           input_shape=(None, 400),  # 20x20 input pixels per batch
           hidden_num_units=100,  # number of units in hidden layer

           # output layer uses identity function
           output_nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.softmax,
           output_num_units=63,

           # optimization method:
           update=nesterov_momentum,
           update_learning_rate=0.01,
           update_momentum=0.9,

           # flag to indicate we're dealing with regression problem
           regression=False,
           max_epochs=400,  # we want to train this many epochs
           verbose=1,
)

net1.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
```

If I select the size as 63, I get the following error:

> > net1.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
> >           File "C:\Users\FTS.fts-gnosis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nolearn\lasagne\base.py", line 539, in fit
> >             self.train_loop(X, y, epochs=epochs)
> >           File "C:\Users\FTS.fts-gnosis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nolearn\lasagne\base.py", line 597, in train_loop
> >             self.apply_batch_func(self.train_iter_, Xb, yb))
> >           File "C:\Users\FTS.fts-gnosis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nolearn\lasagne\base.py", line 687, in apply_batch_func
> >             return func(Xb) if yb is None else func(Xb, yb)
> >           File "C:\Users\FTS.fts-gnosis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 879, in **call**
> >             storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
> >           File "C:\Users\FTS.fts-gnosis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\link.py", line 325, in raise_with_op
> >             reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
> >           File "C:\Users\FTS.fts-gnosis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 866, in **call**
> >             self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
> >         ValueError: y_i value out of bounds
> >         Apply node that caused the error: CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias(Dot22.0, output.b, y_batch)
> >         Toposort index: 11
> >         Inputs types: [TensorType(float64, matrix), TensorType(float64, vector), TensorType(int32, vector)]
> >         Inputs shapes: [(128L, 63L), (63L,), (128L,)]
> >         Inputs strides: [(504L, 8L), (8L,), (4L,)]
> >         Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown']
> >         Outputs clients: [[Sum{acc_dtype=float64}(CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias.0)], [CrossentropySoftmax1HotWithBiasDx(Elemwise{Inv}[(0, 0)].0, CrossentropySoftmaxArgmax1HotWithBias.1, y_batch)], []]  HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'. HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.

If I change the

```
output_nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify
```

I get the following error:

> > File "C:\Users\FTS.fts-gnosis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\nnet\nnet.py", line 1453, in perform
> >             y[i] = -numpy.log(coding[i, one_of_n[i]])
> >         IndexError: index 107 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 63
> >         Apply node that caused the error: CrossentropyCategorical1Hot(Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (Abs(i1) + i2 + i3))}}[(0, 2)].0, y_batch)
> >         Toposort index: 14
> >         Inputs types: [TensorType(float64, matrix), TensorType(int32, vector)]
> >         Inputs shapes: [(128L, 63L), (128L,)]
> >         Inputs strides: [(504L, 8L), (4L,)]
> >         Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
> >         Outputs clients: [[Sum{acc_dtype=float64}(CrossentropyCategorical1Hot.0)]]  Backtrace when the node is created(use Theano flag traceback.limit=N to make it longer):
> >           File "C:\Users\FTS.fts-gnosis\workspace\hello1\facialrec.py", line 200, in 
> >             net1.fit(xTrain, yTrain)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your classes aren't encoded as integers 0-62, in which case you can pass `use_label_encoder=True` to `NeuralNet` to have it do the encoding automatically.